# Way\Generators is breaking Laravel Envoyer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, envoyer.io

I'm trying to transition a Laravel 4.2 site from Forge to Forge/Envoyer.  I'm following the laracast but I keep getting the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider' not
>   found in
>   /home/forge/Site/envoyer/releases/20150511192402/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php
>   on line 157

on the Install Composer Dependencies step of Envoyer deployment.

I've removed the lines for Way/Generators from both `composer.json` and `config/app.php` and have followed [the documentation](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators) to re-install it.  Envoyer works with Way/Generators removed but keeps failing when I add it back.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In composer.json add way/generators inside "require-dev", so it will be downloaded only on your dev machine.

```
"require-dev": {
    "way/generators": "~2.0"
}
```

Add `Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider` only inside your local (development) config - `config/local/app.php`. That way it will be present on your development machine, because it will use `config/local/app.php`, but while deploying, envoyer will use `config/app.php`, where `Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider` are not set.

This is how your `config/local/app.php` can look like:

```
<?php

return array(
    'debug' => true,
    'providers' => append_config(array(
        'Way\Generators\GeneratorsServiceProvider'
    ))
);
```